# Align overlapping text in TextViews

Tags: android, textview

I want two TextViews to overlap such that individual letters will overlap perfectly (i.e. you can't even see there is another TextView on the screen). Here is the relevant part of my layout:

```
<com.testing.android.animals.OutlinedTextView
android:id="@+id/label_left_name"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="Elephant"
android:layout_alignTop="@id/picture_left"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
android:textColor="#ffffff" 
android:textSize="40dp"
android:background="#99000000"
></com.testing.android.animals.OutlinedTextView>

<com.testing.android.animals.OutlinedTextView
android:id="@+id/label_left_letter"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="E"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/label_left_name"
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/label_left_name"
android:textColor="#ffffff" 
android:textSize="40dp"
android:background="#99ffffff"
></com.testing.android.animals.OutlinedTextView>
```

When rendered, it looks like this:

[image]

Notice the individual "E" (in light gray) is aligned too high.

What can I change in the layout that will get them to overlap better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the p makes the bottom of the full word textview taller. and since you have wrap_content as the height, the two heights of the textviews are different.

If you set the height of each textview to a specific size (the same size), they should align.

But in general, i think your approach might be wrong - you may want to either look into spannable strings for formatting or, since it appears you are using a custom control anyway, have it do the formatting of the first letter. (here is an example of spannable strings: http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring )

Comment: I ended up using a Spnnable string that contained the whole word "Elephant" but the "lephant" part was transparent.